# UIMenuController not showing UIPasteBoard is cleared iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, uitextview, uimenucontroller

Am working in message based iPhone application. In my application looking like iMessage native iOS app. `I made Bubbles with used UIImageView and UILabel. I made UILabel as clickable and showing Copy option. It is working fine when the message input UITextView is not in active.`

```
1. I can show the "Copy" option when we clicking UILabel and the UITextView is not becomeFirstResponder.

2. When the user clicking the MessageTextView (UITextView) from the bottom of the screen the UITextView becoming first responder and keyboard is showing now. In this scenario if the user clicking the messabe bubble (UILabel) the UIMenuItem showing "Paste" on the bubble instead of "Copy".

3. If i click "Paste" from the bubble UIMenuItem already copied text will be pasting in UITextView. So the control fully in UITextView UIMenuController not activated in UILabel. So i cleared the text from UIPateBoard when the user clicking the Bubble (UILabel).

4. Now the UIMenuController not showing up even [self becomeFirstResponder]; not becoming in UILabel class.
```

The reason is when the UITextView is in becomeFirstResponder the control fully in that. not coming to UILabel. Could you please help me on this.

`How to show UIMenuItem "Copy" when the user clicking UILabel if the keyboard is in visible the control is in UITextView?` Could you please help me on this. I spent two days in this issue. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: please make clear about your view hierarchy..can you put some screenshot??

Comment: ok good then..hope some image to be clear about your problem

Comment: @R.A i edited my question. Please review that and let me know if you need more informations. Thanks. Looking for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**May be I am wrong.CONSIDER THIS ANSWER AS A COMMENT.**

I tried to achieve like what you are trying to do. Thats not working too. I figured out I cannot make access the `two views` at the same time. Especially when I have any view `becomeFirstResponder` and `you cannot access menu items of other view`.

But if you try like this,you may succeed in your code.

1) In the `touchesBegan:` method, find the user touching inside your UILabel.

2) If that happens, then show a custom view with buttons like `copy,paste and select` like that.

Comment: But how can i show the custom views correctly on the bubbles? Am very weak in calculations. so am trying to do this simply ha ha..

Comment: you dont need to calculate anything. you just need an outlet for that label.. get the position where user touch the view and add your custom view in that position. use locationInView: method to get the user touching location

Comment: r u in chat room? could you please tell me you chat room name? I need you help on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: No i m working too.. try as i said.. if you have any problem, i will reply u here itself.

Comment: Yes friend.. thanks you so much.. i'll let you know if i have any questions. :)